Android Paging3 - How to Check Current Page Number
I'm currently using Paging3 with RecyclerView to show a simple student list (from Room database), this is the setup of my PagingDataSource:
class StudentPagingSource(private val studentDao: StudentDao) : PagingSource<Int, Student>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Student> {
        val totalCount = studentDao.getStudentsCount()
        val initialPage = totalCount / params.loadSize
        val page = params.key ?: initialPage

        return try {
            val students = studentDao.getPagedStudents(params.loadSize, page * params.loadSize)

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = students,
                prevKey = if (page == 0) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (students.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Student>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let {
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(it)

            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }
}

Repository:
class StudentRepository(database: StudentDatabase) {
    companion object {
        const val PAGE_SIZE = 30
    }

    private val studentDao = database.studentDao

    fun getStudentCountFlow() = studentDao.getStudentsCountFlow()

    fun getPagedStudents(): Flow<PagingData<Student>> {
        val pager = Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = PAGE_SIZE,
                enablePlaceholders = false,
                initialLoadSize = PAGE_SIZE
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { StudentPagingSource(studentDao) }
        )

        return pager.flow
    }

    suspend fun saveStudents(vararg student: Student) = studentDao.insert(*student)
}

ViewModel:
class FirstViewModel(
    application: Application,
    private val studentRepository: StudentRepository
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val uiScope = viewModelScope

    val studentsCount = studentRepository.getStudentCountFlow()
    val students = studentRepository.getPagedStudents().cachedIn(uiScope)
}

Fragment:
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    studentAdapter = getStudentAdapter()

    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

    setupOptionsMenu()

    binding.recyclerView.adapter = studentAdapter

    viewModel.students.collectLatestOnStarted(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        studentAdapter.submitData(it)
    }

    viewModel.studentsCount.collectOnStarted(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        studentAdapter.refresh()
    }

    studentAdapter.addOnPagesUpdatedListener {
        scrollToBottom()
    }

    return binding.root
}

private fun scrollToBottom() {   
    if (!binding.recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {  //need to know if it is on last page
        binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(studentAdapter.itemCount - 1)
    }
}

What I want: when the RecyclerView is showing the last page && it reaches the screen bottom -> auto-scroll-to-bottom when there is new data (student) being added to the RecyclerView.
So, how can I get the current page number from Paging?
